# Liquibase cannot find File in an OSGI Bundle

Tags: liquibase, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

I am building an OSGI Bundle with the apache bundle plugin and deploy it on a Karaf Instance.
I have implemented Liquibase in my Bundle Activator in the following way:

```
String Config = bundleContext.getBundle().getResource("com/test/db.changelog-master.xml").getPath();

Liquibase liquibase = new Liquibase(Config, new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
```

I now get the following exception:

```
liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: /com/test/db.changelog-master.xml does not exist
```

Yet the Resource apparently does exist as bundle.getResource returns a path.
I have also checked the JAR and it does contain my file.

So what is the reason for Liquibase not being able to find the xml file?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using the OSGIResourceAccessor instead of the ClassLoaderResourceAccessor().